# Two html files with the same content, in the same folder, with the same browser, in one utf-8 works and in the other it doesn't

Tags: html, windows, utf-8

I'll preface this by stating that I can actually make it work, I just don't know why it works like it does.

The following happens:

I have two files, let's call them File 1 and File 2, both html files, File 2 being blank.

File 1 has one single problem, the utf-8 codification doesn't work, characters like "ñ" or "á" are not displayed properly.

Selecting all of the code in File 1 and pasting it into File 2 results into File 2 working properly, previously mentioned characters work perfectly.

On the other hand, copying and pasting File 1 results in another file which, like File 1, doesn't work, doing the same with File 2 results in the copy of File 2 working, like File 2 does.

Copying and pasting from File 2 to File 1 results in File 1 not working, yet deleting all of the content in File 1, saving it, pasting the contents from File 2 and saving yet again results in File 1 now working.

Examining both files with WinMerge returns a message that they are identical (Spanish though).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFex1.png

Naming also changes nothing.**THE ONE DIFFERENCE** I've been able to find is that the filesize is not actually identical, 2005 bytes to 2013 bytes, and I can't explain the reason, when I delete the contents from File 1, save it, paste the contents from File 2 and save it again, the filesizes are the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPZD8.png

The contents of either html file are these (copypasted from File 1, which doesn't work properly by itself, but the pasted version works):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Cosáññ</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
 </head>
  <body>
 <form class="formulario">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p class="obligatorio">* Campos obligatorios</p>
   <h1>Formulario de contacto 2</h1>
   <p>Si desea contactar, por favor rellene este breve formulario y nos
     comunicaremos con usted lo antes posible.<p>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
   <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="María Rodríguez">
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>
   <label class="notexto" for="sexo">Sexo: </label>
   <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="1"  checked="checked"> mujer
   <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="2"> hombre
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>
   <label>Suplementos:</label>
  </li>
  <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Comedor" value="1"/>
   <label class="casilla" for="Comedor"> Comedor </label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Extraescolar" value="2"/>
   <label class="casilla" for="Extraescolar"> Extraescolar </label>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>
   <label for="contraseña">Contraseña: </label>
   <input type="password" name="contraseña"/>
   </li>
  <br>
  <li>
   <label >Curso: </label>
   <select name "listacurso">
    <option value="1">1dw3</option>
    <option value="2">2dw3</option>
    <option value="3">1as3</option>
    <option value="4">2as3</option>
   </select>
  </li>
   <br>
  <li>
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="fct015110@yahoo.es" required/>
   <span class="texto_ayuda">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>
   <label for="busqueda"> Buscar: </label>
   <input name="busqueda" type="search" placeholder="Formato"/>
  </li>
   <br/>
  <li>
   <label for="inicio"> Fecha de inicio: </label>
   <input name="inicio" type="date" placeholder="selecciona fecha"/>
  </li>
   <br/>
  <input type = "submit">
 </ul>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The files previously pointed to a css file, but for the sake of troubleshooting I removed the reference.

What might be causing this? The OS I'm using is Win7.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the files on your local drive? Seems that only just File2 is UTF8-encoded.

Comment: Please specify *how* characters like “ñ” and “á” are displayed. The odds are that File2 is actually not UTF-8 encoded but UTF-16 encoded, and probably a byte dump is needed to analyze the situation, but the display may give a sufficient clue.

Comment: So it would seem, at least notepad++ displays one of them as ANSI while the other is UTF-8 w/o BOM.

As for how such characters are displayed, they are displayed properly in one of them while the other had a tilted square with a question mark instead.